How to remap PCIe Bar addresses on Linux and x86 and how is configuration space assigned MMIO?
I have doubts of how PCIe subsystem in Linux on x86 works in detail.
For as far as I know to be able to talk to a PCIe device with only mmio the following need to happen:

PCIe Configuration Space must be mapped somehow to mmio.

I read that this is done in bus enumeration?
And that currently there is somethin called ECAM that reserves 256MB for all BDFs.
So I would not be able to map the configuration space to arbitrary physical address?

After config space, the PCie BAR space need to be mapped also.

At boot this is done by the firmware? So is this manufacturer (motherboard) dependent?
What if I want to change this mapping or hot plug, how does a phy address get assigned?
How does that work on x86?
I would need to make sure that the new physical addresses do not collide with already assigned ones?
I know how to write a pcie driver but these low level details for some reason are very hard to find, especially intel docs on how to setup PCIe and mmio mappings.

Do you just want to find out the details for educational purposes? As a writer of a device driver for a PCI device, you generally do not need to worry about how the PCI BARs were initialized as they will have already been mapped to PCI host memory addresses before the driver's probe function is called.

@IanAbbott Educational purposes, I know that once pcie subsystem calls (*probe) it's already assigned. Just out of curiosity if I wanted to change the BAR address to some other one, how would I do that? How does the CPU know to redirect this new range of PA to the device? What happens if it collides with something assigned to DRAM? For all I know now, you just change it, make sure it does not collide and CPU magically finds its way to the PCIe no changing ACPI tables just write into the config space.

PCIe configuration space appears at a fixed MMIO address. This is controlled by either hardware or BIOS and the address cannot be changed by software. Software discovers the address by reading the ACPI table called 'MCFG'. Of course software can map it to an arbitrary virtual address.
Device BARs are also configured by the BIOS. They can be changed by software, but there are some limitations, so generally software just leaves the BARs set to the values set by BIOS. Software can read the BARs directly to discover the addresses. Again these physical addresses need to be mapped into virtual address space before they can be accessed.
With hot plug, system software does need to assign BAR values. Yes, the software that does this does needs to identify suitable memory ranges and avoid conflicts.

Do you know what specifically done on x86 to Software map or remap of BARs? Also how does Linux do it?

@WeijieChen, this is written in the PCIe specifications. Linux almost no difference to other OSes.
